# How do I return a value from a specific field in a different collection in Meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I've bought the Discover Meteor book and gone through the tutorial. I am still unsure of a few sections and have run into a problem which I can't get working.

I have two collections.

```
Computers = new Mongo.Collection('computers');
Apps = new Mongo.Collection("apps");
```

On the server I am publishing:

```
Meteor.publish('computers', function() {
  return Computers.find();
});

Meteor.publish('apps', function() {
  return Apps.find();
});
```

On the client subscribing using Iron Router:

```
Router.configure({
  waitOn: function() {
    return [Meteor.subscribe('computers'), 
            Meteor.subscribe('apps'), 
            Meteor.subscribe('users')];
  }
});
```

In one collection I have referenced a document with the id of another document in another collection.

```
Computers.insert({
  _id: sd9f9sdf699,
  name: 'Mac1'
});

Apps.insert({
  _id: ewf4y34349f,
  name: 'App One',
  version: '1.0',
  computerId: sd9f9sdf699
});
```

I am then using an {{#each}} block to iterate through the documents in the apps collection

```
{{#each apps}}
  {{> appItem}}
{{/each}

<template name="appItem">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checked" class="ui checkbox"></td>
    <td>{{name}}</td>
    <td>{{version}}</td>
    <td>{{computerName}}</td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

and when I get to the computerId field, I would like to match the document in the computers collection and then return the name of the computer instead of the id.

Here is my app_item.js code:

```
Template.appItem.helpers({
  computerName: function() {
    var id = this.computerId;
    var compName = Computers.find({_id: id}, {fields: {name: 1} }).fetch();
    return compName;
  }
});
```

I am obviously missing something here but I can't seem to wrap my head around what it is.

If possible I would please prefer an answer that would teach me what I am doing wrong instead of a copy & paste solution on how to fix it. I seem to have a problem understanding this and would appreciate any advice what programming theory I should be reviewing.

Thanks for reading!
Piotr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your helper code should use findOne() instead of find() function. find() returns coursor that has function fetch() which returns array. findOne() returns one document.

```
Template.appItem.helpers({
  computerName: function() {
    var comp = Computers.findOne(this.computerId, {fields: {name: 1} });
    return comp.name;
  }
});
```

This is one way how to handle joins in Meteor. I've found better way: http://meteor.hromnik.com/blog/joins-in-meteorjs-and-mongodb

Answer (score 2):

One thing you could consider is changing your datamodel to more of a mongo style document structure where you are storing the computerid + computername both on in the apps collection. This prevents extra queries and the only downside is you need to update 2 fields instead of 1 when youre changing the computer values in a specific app document.
You can then simply display the computername with {{computerName}} without the need for a helper.

You could also store each app-computer relation in an array in the computer collection so you can easily request all installed apps on a certain computer without the need to run extra queries for each and every app. But this is not really needed in this case since both collection contain so few fields and you could just get all apps with a simple mongo query as well. Another usefull field (just a guess) could be something like installedAppsAmount in the computer document so you can list the amount of apps on each coputer without extra queries.
All of this is based on assumptions tho and really depends on your usecase.

Hope this is usefull for you.

Im not really sure why your example is not working tho based on this info: is this.computerId correct in your helper and what is compname returning if you display it in your console?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would prefer to get it working with seperate collections as I have the same problem in other parts of the applications, such as assigning a computer to a user, assigning an attachment (such as a pdf) to an app, user, or computer. I also understand this is not ideally the way to go with a datastore like Mongo but I've decided to learn Meteor instead of going the Rails+SQL route. I've also cut a lot out of my code above to keep this post shorter. Console.log(compName) returns an object. I then also tried using {{computerName.name}} but that didn't work either.

Comment: Ok, since its an object, you have to loop through it to get the value you need, but since its always only 1 result you can use findOne as Tomas mentioned in his answer to just return 1 result as an array and retun that.